# parse a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
txt = 'text1 & ("text2" | "text3" | "text4") & "text5" ! (text6 | text7 | text8)'
```

Lets say I want to parse it so I end up with elements that are between parenthesis. My pattern looks like

```
pattern = '\(([^\)(]+)\)'
```

using python I end up with two groups

```
>>> print re.findall(pattren, text)
['"text2" | "text3" | "text4"', 'text6 | text7 | text8']
```

Lets say we want to find some thing like

```
>>> print re.findall(magic_pattren, text )
['& ("text2" | "text3" | "text4")', '! (text6 | text7 | text8)']
```

Any guesses on what that `magic_pattren` would be. I can work my way to the desired output using string operations.

```
 >>> print [txt[str.find(txt, a)-3: 1+len(a)+str.find(txt, a)] for a in re.findall(pattren, txt)]
 ['& ("text2" | "text3" | "text4")', '! (text6 | text7 | text8)']
```

But this feels a bit clunky and fails if the parenthesis group is in the beginning. I can add a check on that, but like I said feels a bit clunky. Any takers?

Comment: Please check [this demo](https://ideone.com/4ifC5g) with the `r'\B\W\s*\([^()]+\)'` regex.

Comment: Thanks for that, but this will miss if the group is in start. https://ideone.com/eWvumU

Comment: So, make that part optional, [see this update](https://ideone.com/0kR8rV)

Comment: Got that.. gold thats what this is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `(?:\B\W\s*)?` optional group at the beginning of the pattern:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?:\B\W\s*)?\([^()]+\)')
test_str = "(text9 & text10) & text1 & (\"text2\" | \"text3\" | \"text4\") & \"text5\" ! (text6 | text7 | text8)"
print(p.findall(test_str))
```

Result of the [sample demo](https://ideone.com/0kR8rV): `['(text9 & text10)', '& ("text2" | "text3" | "text4")', '! (text6 | text7 | text8)']`

The `(?:\B\W\s*)?` is a non-capturing group (so that the value is not output in the result) that can be repeated one or zero times (due to the last `?`), and it matches a non-word character (`\W`) only if it is preceded with a non-word character or start of string (`\B`) and followed with 0+ whitespace.

[Here is the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO2iU7/3)